# Calculate hanging cable between two poles (having cable length and height of poles )

Tags: java

I want to simulate a hanging cable between two powerline poles. For that I need to know the y position for any point on the cable. I tried this formula from wikipedia, but it does not work right.

```
    for(int i= 0; i<20;i++){
        double cosh = 20*Math.cosh(i/20);
        worldRenderer.addVertex(posX+i, posY+22-cosh, posZ);
    }
```

It just draws a straight line 20 meters below the anchor point of the cable.

Comment: Use `double cosh = 20*Math.cosh(i/20.);` - i/20 returns 0 because it's evaluated as an `int`.

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm curious on a personal level why you posted that answer as a comment? Mistake; couldn't be bothered; something else?

Comment: It changed something, but still just half of the cable is drawn. And can you tell me what is the length of the cable in that formular?

Comment: fixed that issue in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when dividing by 20, make sure you use 20.0, so java knows to use a double, otherwise it will always round down as an int

FULL FIX:

```
for(int i= 0; i<20;i++){
    double cosh = 20*Math.cosh(i/20.0);
    worldRenderer.addVertex(posX+i, posY+22-cosh, posZ);
    if(i!=0&&i!=19){
        worldRenderer.addVertex(posX+i, posY+22-cosh, posZ);
    }
}
```

this works because when you draw a line, it takes two vertices, a start and end, but if you only add one vertex per point, you dont specify the start of the next line

Comment: Omg, thanks - you must know, i didn't learn jave by reading a book or watching tutorials, but by writing minecraft mods, so im missing some basic stuff :/

Comment: no way, I learned it the same way, also as another note, you could say 20D to cast it as a double the same way that you would say 20L to cast it as a long

Comment: also, i am not sure if you are aware, but cosh(0) is 1

Comment: Yea :D Im no mathmatical genius atm, i have holidays :P

Comment: Oh, im just using GL11.GL_LINE_STRIP, that just connecs all given points to a line :D

Comment: Kore, can you tell me how i can change how far the chain is hanging down?

Comment: the length of the chain hanging down can be found by multiplying your cosh by more or less e.g 15×cosh is less and 25×cosh is more

Comment: Thank you - you really helped me out!

Comment: Okay, one more problem, if i scale it up, i somehow need to get the start/end of the rope back to their originall position. How can i calculate the correct angle?

Comment: change posy+22-cosh, and adjust 22 to fit your scenario

Comment: Yea i actually added in a scalefactor variable which changes depending on the distance between the polls, so if the cable is really long it will hang depper than if it is short :D

Comment: nice, what are you gonna do with that, or is it just a POC

Comment: I need it for my mod, ill post a link once i release the new version(in about two weeks) But before that i have another question. For now the cable is always hanging 90/180 degrees, but i want it to be able to hang like 32 degrees etc, so i thought about using sin/cos for that but i dunno how its right. In my forloop, should i just have the sin(rotationangle)*i?

Comment: sorry, i was catching up with school homework, the line that you see shouldnt have hard edges(90/180) unless something is wrong